# Can I know how the language interoperability works in .NET with the help of example?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-c++

I was reading about the .NET framework and I read that ".NET provides language interoperability", and I also read the answer to the question [What is language interoperability (basic concept) in .net framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242590/what-is-language-interoperability-basic-concept-in-net-framework), but I don't have any idea about how to use this feature practically.

Comment: I think the answers to the question you linked are quite clear. You can use libraries written in any .Net language from any other .Net language. As a practical example, Json.Net is written in C# but you can use it perfectly well from VB.Net or F#. I don't know what else I could say...

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple project using C#, make a simple class and compile it. You will generate a .dll.
Then create a project using VB and import/include the one you compiled where you used C#. VB won´t take care of your C# code, but it can manage the class you created.

How? Because .NET is compiled in a common language. Does not matter if you have used C# or VB to generate the code.

Interoperability is a framework feature. Is rare that you need make use of this for small projects so I undestand you don't find a real way to carry out. But it is that simple as all what you do with C# in .NET you can reuse if you decide code in VB in the future or for some parts of a project.

In practice programmers decide to code in one language. But reusability is already there.

Feel free to ask what you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43417187/7733724